# ElasticSearch - Filter results by inner hits

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-5

We have a simple index of entities with mapping:

```
PUT resource/_mapping/entity
{
  "properties": {
    "id": {
      "type": "keyword"
    },
    "name": {
      "type": "keyword"
    },
    "claims": {
      "type": "nested",
      "properties": {
        "claimid": {
          "type": "keyword"
        },
        "priority": {
          "type": "short"
        },
        "visibility": {
          "type": "keyword"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Here's a sample document in the index:

```
POST resource/entity/
{
  "id": "2",
  "name": "e2",
  "claims": [
    {
      "claimid": "c1",
      "priority": "2",
      "visibility": "M",
      "reqid" : "2"
    },
    {
      "claimid": "c2",
      "priority": "1",
      "visibility": "V",
      "reqid" : "2"
    },
    {
      "claimid": "c5",
      "priority": "3",
      "visibility": "H",
      "reqid" : "2"
    }
  ]
}
```

And a query to filter documents by provided set of 'claims.claimid', then to sort by 'claims.priority', select the one with highest priority and return only the 'claims.visibility' e.g.:

```
GET resource/entity/_search/
{
  "query": {
    "nested": {
      "path": "claims",
      "query": {
        "bool": {
          "must": [
            {
              "terms": {
                "claims.claimid": [
                  "c1",
                  "c4",
                  "c5"
                ]
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      },          
      "inner_hits": {
        "sort": [
          {
            "claims.priority": "asc"
          }
        ],
        "size":1,
        "_source":{"includes":["claims.visibility"]}
      }
    }
  }
}
```

And finally the problem to be solved: how to modify the query to filter out documents having resulted in "H" for visibility with highest priority in inner hits? Or what other query will return a set of documents with visibility of highest priority filtered by provided claim ids, but only those where visibility is not "H"?

A catch here is that we have to sort the documents having all types of visibilities and filter out those with resulting "H" on a complete list of results.